# Vue router not navigating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm having problems getting VueRouter to navigate.
Within my app some pages work fine, and with identical code, other pages the routing doesn't work / page doesn't update navigate.

Are there some gotchas with the router? Like you cannot call the router from within components or... ?

named route in my app

```
export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/grams/one/:cname',
      component: GramsOne,
      name: "gramsOne"
    },
  ...
```

Then inside a component on a page:

```
<q-btn v-for='(rel, key) in gram.relatedItems' :key='key'
  color='secondary'
  @click="goGram(rel)"
  >
  {{rel.cn}}
</q-btn>


// later in the script:

  methods: {
    goGram(gram) {
      let newRoute = {
        name: 'gramsOne',
        params: {cname: gram.cname}
      }
      console.log('goGram', newRoute)
      this.$router.push(newRoute)
    }
  },
```

Elsewhere on the same page, simple routes work.
The URL address will get updated in the browser.
I see the right console log with route info

But the page/content will not change.

Once the URL bar has been updated, I can hit ctrl-R and the new page will get loaded. So the destination route is working fine.

From other pages in the same app I can use the same route to target new destination and loads fine.

This is also loading with the same URL and just a query param different that is causing the problem.

/app/items/foo
/app/items/bar

where `bar` is a type of some property `/app/items/:foo`

I have tried various combinations of named routes, routes using  etc, and can't really see a pattern.

```
"vue": "~2.5.0",
"vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
"vue-router": "^2.7.0"
```

Thanks any hints!

Comment: Since you are using the same component, Vue does not trigger a re-render. Try adding a `key` attribute to your `router-view` like so: `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />`.

Comment: @Ricky Just a note that I had the same issue and adding a key to my `<router-view>` element worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Component in this case is the same, so vue will reuse the instance. 
The `this.$route` in the component will change but `created()`, `beforeMounted()` and `mounted()` hooks won't be callled.
Which is probably where you use the `this.$route.params.cname`

To force vue to create a new component instance you can set a unique key on the like `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath">`

Another options is to react to changes in the `$route` with a watcher:

```
watch: {
  "$route.params.cname": {
    handler(cname) {
      // do stuff
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Router can be called within a component just fine. In fact, you usually call router from the component.

From the code snippets provided, at one point in the code you use `cn`, then at other point you use `cname`. That might be the problem why it never quite work for you.

I create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5ozrp935) to recreate your scenario, and besides that minor naming mentioned above, things seem to work just fine.